# How to create a performant logger in java

Tags: java, logging

I want to create a custom logger (for a minecraft plugin) to log important events. I also want the logger to be somewhat efficient in terms of performance.

What's the appropriate way of doing this. All I have as an example is the minecraft logfile and a bunch of tutorials I read. But they all seem, except from the mc logger, to be inefficient or have other drawbacks.
So my Question is: 
*"What's the best / goto / most efficient way of creating a live logger, which logs in realtime to a file?*
Here are some approaches I found:

1. Create the whole logger yourself. Whenever you want to write a logmessage, open the file -> write -> close file.
2. Use the Java Logger with a `FileHandler()` as a handler of the logger (This will create a nasty .lck file, which makes the logfile not live.
3. Whenever you want to write a message to the logfile create a new `FileHandler()` -> add it to the logger -> write the message -> remove it as a handler from the Logger -> close the FileHandler. (This seems super slow in terms of performance)

```java
public void info(String message) {
    try {
        this.logFile = new FileHandler("logs" + File.separator + fileName + ".log", true);
        this.logFile.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.logger.addHandler(this.logFile);
    this.logger.info(message);
    this.logger.removeHandler(this.logFile);
    this.logFile.close();
}
```

  5.

Comment: Why not use [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/)?

Comment: SLF4J and Logback as implementation.

Comment: @DasElias Legacy log4j is obsolete; log4j2 is the updated replacement, and I usually see slf4j as a frontend API.

Comment: Use whatever Minecraft already uses.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, of course, you're right. I actually linked the website of log4j2, but I wrote "log4j" in my comment.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen But this will write everything in the main log, which will make it super painfull for the admin to find anything related to my plugin.